# How to create a simple MFC uniform color HICON icon by code?

Tags: c++, mfc, icons, controls

This is hopefully simple: I have an application which uses CListCtr in report mode and I want to assign icons to the entries. The icons should be simple square uniformly coloured icons 16x16.

I know ( - *I think I know* - ) how to handle `CListCtr` and `CImageList`, but the challenge I have is the following:

- The icon colour is created by the code and arbitrary COLORREF
- The icons are not created as files in my resources but should be created by code also. If need be, there can be one 'template' icon in which a specific color is replaced by COLORREF from above.

Essentially, I want to 'abuse' the images as kind of status-light in my CListCtr but with arbitrary colour.

Can anybody give me a short example code snipped for:

**Creating a `HICON` element which is a 16x16 uniformly filled bitmap of `COLORREF` specified colour?**

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try something like this:

```
CDC dc;
dc.CreateCompatibleDC(NULL);

m_bitmap.CreateBitmap(16, 16, dc.GetDeviceCaps(PLANES), dc.GetDeviceCaps(BITSPIXEL), NULL);
m_imageList.Create(16, 16, ILC_COLORDDB, 0, 1);

HGDIOBJ hOld = dc.SelectObject(m_bitmap);
dc.FillSolidRect(0, 0, 16, 16, RGB(0xff, 0, 0));
dc.SelectObject(hOld);
m_imageList.Add(&m_bitmap, RGB(0, 0, 0));
m_listCtrl.SetImageList(&m_imageList, LVSIL_SMALL);

m_listCtrl.InsertItem(0, _T("hello"), 0);
```

Comment: Thanks. With slight modifications (see post below) it does exactly what I want. I've wrapped it into a method to return a HICON and I use a [trick from here](http://forum.codejock.com/forum_posts.asp?TID=9245) to get the HICON when I have a HBITMAP.

Answer (score 0):

My advise is not to create icons in this way.

Just use NM_CUSTOMDRAW to draw the element by yourself. You find a great explanation here in this two articles. With this code it is simple to draw the specified area in the color you want!

[Article1](http://www.codeguru.com/cpp/controls/listview/customdrawing/article.php/c4195/Custom-Draw-ListView-Controls-Part-I.htm) [Article2](http://www.codeguru.com/cpp/controls/listview/customdrawing/article.php/c4199/Custom-Draw-ListView-Controls-Part-II.htm)

Creating an icon is possible with [CreateIconIndirect](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms648062(v=vs.85).aspx). You just need to create 2 bitmaps. The drawback here is you need to destroy all theicons you create.
h

Comment: Thanks for the advise. Can you explain why you're advising against using HICONS? The solution seem to work fine and is simple enough. I've to check out the two articles though.

Comment: Any color can be used at any time and the drawing is only done when needed. When you create an icon, you have to create bitmaps, than icons, than store them in an image list, and do all the cleanup. Why should you do this when all can be done with a simple FilRect.

Answer (score 0):

Slight modification to the ***accepted answer from mockfrog*** above.

This also uses the trick I've learnt of [here](http://forum.codejock.com/forum_posts.asp?TID=9245): Using `CImageList` to convert from `HBITMAP` to `HICON`.

Note that it's important to use  `ILC_COLOR32` to get the full range of colours and not some unwanted colour casting.

```
HICON CCMixTP_Dialog::CreateColorIcon2( COLORREF color )
{
  CDC dc;
  dc.CreateCompatibleDC(NULL);
  CBitmap bitmap;
  bitmap.CreateBitmap(16, 16, dc.GetDeviceCaps(PLANES), \
     dc.GetDeviceCaps(BITSPIXEL), NULL);
  CImageList convertBuffer;
  convertBuffer.Create(16, 16, ILC_COLOR32, 1, 1);

  HGDIOBJ hOld = dc.SelectObject(bitmap);
  dc.FillSolidRect(0, 0, 16, 16, color);
  dc.SelectObject(hOld);

  convertBuffer.Add( &bitmap, RGB(0,0,0) ); // Mask black pixels as black.
  return convertBuffer.ExtractIcon(0);
}
```